# How we can modify Google logo on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

When I use Google maps api v2, Google maps comes with Google logo on lower left and some more trademark on lower right.[image]

But recently I came across an app on play store [Fake Location Spoofer Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incorporateapps.fakegps.fre). This app has a modified Google Logo as shown in below image [image]

I Googled how can I modify Google logo but I could not find anything relevant. So anyone has any idea how they modified it? One more thing, I used this app on [Bluestacks app player](http://www.bluestacks.com/), this is the only app in which map is rendering very well. So what so special with this app. I used other apps too like [FakeGps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps) but it is not rendering well in Bluestacks app player.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is a bad idea and it is probably required in the licence to show it.

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I think same but Spoofer app is doing this. Look at screen shot.

Comment: there is also Google icon appeared

Comment: @SathishKumarJ   Look at the difference sir!!

Comment: that may be depends upon the maps version

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android hierarchyviewer tool to find the ID of the Google logo in the view hierarchy, then get a reference to this view using `findViewById` and changing its visibility.

However, I would first read the Google Maps ToS to ensure this is not a violation subject to legal implications.

Answer (score -2):

Spoofer app is using Google maps api version 1. Google has deprecated api version 1, so new developers can not use it. But the apps using api version 1 can continue with this. Map container has been changed in latest api, that's why apps using latest api version is not rendering correctly on Bluestacks.